# How to increase UIView height in UItableView using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I am new to iOS Programming, I have implemented `UITableviewController`. I placed `UIView` inside of `UITableView`. I designed label, textfields and tableview inside of `UIView`. Here My problem is, When I increasing the dynamic tableview based on array count, I want to increase my `UIView` height also. I don't know how to do that?? Below is my design structure,

```
UITableViewController---          
       UIView-----               (1)
           Label---Label         (2)
           label---Label         (3)
           label---              (4)
           UItableview           (5)
           textfield             (6)
           textfield             (7)
and so on
```

below I have successfully increase the (5) height and also I want to increase (1) height I don't know how to do?? can any one suggest solution for this?? I have tried this below code.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{


    CGFloat numberofrows=creditList.count;
    height = numberofrows*propertytable.rowHeight;
    _tableviewheight.constant = height;

    propertytable.frame =CGRectMake(propertytable.frame.origin.x,propertytable.frame.origin.y, propertytable.frame.size.width,_tableviewheight.constant);
    CGRect myviewframe=mainview.frame;
    NSLog(@"The myviewframe value is %f",myviewframe.size.height);


    mainview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;
    myviewframe.size.height=5000;

    mainview.frame=myviewframe;
    mainview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,mainview.frame.size.width, 5000);
    mainview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    mainview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[mainview layoutIfNeeded];

      }
```

Comment: UILabel(1) and UILabel(2) are static or dynamic ?

Comment: Why you used another tableview inside a table view controller. You can use sections or if first view is static take it as table view header. You can drag a uiview into table view. If you know auto layouts dynamic height of table view cell is very easy.

Comment: It not a tableviewcontroller,I used tableview I want to populate the array values dynamically that Why I used??

Comment: I mentioned that number are static I designed my ui into view.the only (5) tableview is dynamic

Comment: After Increased (5) height I can't scroll upto bottom because I want to increase my uiview height also.

Comment: do you know auto layout concept?@ShubamGupta

Comment: I know to set the auto constraints in storyboard

Comment: Ok then give bottom layout to last Label of UIView and set view height constraint as greater than or equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If object has autolayout, try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 105; //Default Height
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```